# Error functions

Tags: probability, mathematical-physics

I would like to ask if it's possible to solve for the derivative of the error function of $x^3$.

$$\frac{d}{dx} \operatorname{erf}(x^3)$$

I only have little understanding about this topic but I know that
$$ \operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt$$

So, if I solve for $\operatorname{erf}(x^3)$ first, is it correct to just change the bounds from 0 to $x^3$ and then solve it from there?

Answer (score 1):

[Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) is actually **defined** as the integral of the Gaussian function as
$$
\text{erf}(x)\triangleq\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\int_0^x \exp(-t^2)dt,
$$
hence you can find the derivative by using
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=g'(x)f'(g(x))
$$

Comment: For clarification is f(g(x)) = erf(x^3)? If so, then does that mean that the result that I should be getting is just the product of the derivative of x^3 and e^-t^2

Comment: By the chain rule: $(f\circ g)'=((f'\circ g)\cdot g')$. $~$ Take $f(u)=\operatorname{erf}(u)$ and $g(v)=v^3$. $~$  So ... $$\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d x}\operatorname{erf}(x^3) = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$$Now $g'(v)=3v^2$ and $f'(u)=\frac 2{\surd\pi}\exp(-u^2)$, because $f(u)=\frac 2{\surd\pi}\int\limits_0^u\exp(-t^2)\mathrm d t$.

Comment: @MathNewb, yes, but you have to replace back $x^3$ in $\exp(-t^2)$ by the chain rule. So, here is the full step: 1) find the derivative of $x^3$ 2) find the derivative of $\text{erf}(x)$ (which is $\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\exp(-x^2)$) 3) replace $x^3$ in $\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\exp(-x^2)$ 4) multiply the derivative of $x^3$ in the result of step 3.

Answer (score 1):

With a simple change of integration variables
$$
\operatorname{erf}(x^3 ) = \frac{2}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\int_0^{x^3 } {e^{ - t^2 } dt}\; \mathop  = \limits^{\; t = s^3 } \; \frac{6}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\int_0^x {s^2 e^{ - s^6 } ds} .
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{d}{{dx}}\operatorname{erf}(x^3 ) = \frac{6}{{\sqrt \pi  }}x^2 e^{ - x^6 }. 
$$